# Why is VideoView widget taking almost full height?

Tags: android, xml, android-videoview

Why is the `VideoView` taking up so much space?

My `RecyclerView` contains of a header part (for the `VideoView`) and an item part.

[image: Header]

It tried to fix it with `match_parent` and `wrap_content` but the result was still the same.

Right below the video (in the gray area) should be the `ListItems`. At least one you can see at the bottom of the screen.

**main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**header.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/videoViewHeader"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `RelativeLayout` tag `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of **item.xml** and **header.xml** to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I tried that too but then the `VideoView` is not shown anymore.